# Where can I find free web hosting for my Perl application?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, perl

I'm learning Perl and I wrote a simple application which I want to host. I would prefer free hosting, because as I'm just learning and my project is very simple.

Comment: Could you make this question community wiki please? It's not a suitable question for gaining reputation points.

Comment: Ok, turning it into community wiki!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply set up a machine (or virtual machine) with Apache and anything else you need? That way you can experiment and fiddle to your heart's content. If you use a hosting service and something doesn't work you're going to have a bit of trouble working out the cause, especially as you are just starting out.